# mongoose model $in query not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run a query on mongodb with mongoose when accessing my API, however this doesn't work. It always sends me an error.

If I search on mongo client with **db.my_collection.find({ingredient_name: ["olive","oil"]})** then it works perfectly.

my code looks like below:

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  var tmp = req.params.id.split(",");
  var search = JSON.stringify(tmp);
  console.log("searching for "+search);

  ComplementaryFood.find({
    ingredient_name : { $in : search }
  } ,function (err, complementary_food) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!complementary_food) { return res.send(404); }
    return res.json(complementary_food);
  });
};
```

**search** is a JSON like ["olive","oil"] or ["beer"], etc.

Please help, I've already read the moongose documentation, tried a lot of different things and none worked ...

*btw. my project is built upon angular-fullstack-generator from yoman*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$in` takes an array value, not a string. So don't stringify `tmp`, just use it directly:

```
ComplementaryFood.find({
    ingredient_name : { $in : tmp }
}, ...
```